# Ways to Import Data into a SQL database from another database or bak file

Tags: sql-server

I need to move the data from an existing SQL database to a new SQL database. I cant do a restore on the new SQL database because I need the tables to be generated through the migrations first. So I need a way to just move the data. I've tried using the SLQ Server Import Export Wizard but its a tedious process since I have to manually import a few tables at a time since the order matters. Does anyone know of a faster or more efficient way of importing data in this situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would an SSIS package work? Can develop it to do certain tables before doing others.

Comment: "*I cant do a restore on the new SQL database because I need the tables to be generated through the migrations first.*" - Can you clarify what you mean by this?...You have a series of migration scripts you need to run against the tables? If they are altering the tables to match what they currently are in the existing database, then why do you need to run them at all if you restored a database backup instead?

Comment: @J.D. I upgraded my backend to entity framework core which led to me updating model mapping code. In order for me to confirm the code works I need to run the migrations and model mapping code and then import the data. If I can do that without any errors or inconsistency's then I know it worked. A back up restore would go around what Im trying to test

Comment: So just to clarify, the migrations you have are from any entity changes that occurred after you updated your backend to use EF Core? Are you taking Transaction Log backups on your source database?...if so, how frequently?

Comment: @J.D. correct, all of the migrations are different due to the entity changes after updating to EF Core. Yes I am taking Transaction Log backups every 30 minutes

Comment: Why not restore backups up to your latest Transaction Log backup prior to whenever you cutover to EF Core?...then the tables should essentially be in the same state for you to be able to run the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

If right click on a database under "Tasks" you can "Generate Scripts...".
When you get to the end of the wizard there is an Advanced option, under this an option "Types of data to script" from the drop down you can select "Schema and Data".
This will create a script that will correctly generate tables and insert data.

Comment: Just about fine for a few 10s of thousands of rows , above that it will get painful

Answer (score 0):

BCP is a command line tool that is installed with SQL Server. It can dump all the data from a table to a disk file, or load a table from that disk file.

Write a script (PowerShell?) to iterate over the source's tables. Call `bcp out *table*...` to dump to file *table*.data. The mirror script can iterate over the disk directory and load the files to the target tables.

There are many options for controlling the file format (CSV, native etc.), using a query over a full dump, and so forth.

If the source & target tables have the same columns in the same order with the same type this is easy. If there are a few differences you can write manual queries for the exceptions. With many differences one can use table descriptor files though this becomes tedious to automate.